# emacs23 menu problem

Tags: emacs, emacs23

After some upgrades my emacs23 stopped work properly. Some item in the main menu  could not be open. After F10 they start to work.
I reinstalled emacs - it does not help. 
(I am using ubuntu 10.10 on Dell Latitude).
I will be thankful for any suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Could you please be more specific? Usually `M-x accelerate-menu` helps when the menu option doesn't expand.

Answer (score 0):

I have issues with things not working quite often when I take a new emacs version. Usually it is some old custom emacs stuff of mine that no longer works. (I still have some lines in there that date back to the 20th Century).

Try renaming your `.emacs` file to something else (and then starting a new emacs session, of course). If that fixes the issue, you can put it back, then selectively comment out portions of it until you find the culprit.

If you have site-lisp set to somewhere besides the emacs tree itself, it could also be something in there (although usually you can track that down to start with via the .emacs file as mentioned above). If you don't have site-lisp set outside your emacs tree, it could be that your .emacs file is looking for something in site-lisp that isn't in the new installation's site-lisp directory.

Comment: you don't need to rename .emacs only use the --no-init-file option

Answer (score 0):

You could also try more recent emacs23:  https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-elisp/+archive/ppa. I actually had some libraries that didn't work properly with 23.1 that is in the 10.10 repos.

Answer (score 0):

To add to T.E.D.'s suggestion: When trying to debug your `.emacs` file, use a binary search. Comment out half of it (using command `comment-region`), then 3/4, then 7/8... until you locate the culprit.  Command `comment-region` also *un*comments the region -- check its doc.